# bootstrap popover with reactjs (JSX)

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, reactjs

I am trying to use bootstraps popover button with html inside it, but I get Unexpected token errors when building the JSX.

Here is what I want to do in JSX:

```
<button type="button" className="btn btn-secondary" data-container="body"
        data-toggle="popover" data-placement="bottom"
        data-content="<button type="button" className="btn btn-danger pull-xs-left" data-dismiss="modal">Delete</button>">
        data-html="true"
        Popover on bottom
 </button>
```

But react doesn't like building data-content:

```
data-content="<button type="button" className="btn btn-danger pull-xs-left"
```

Throws: Unexpected token

```
> 1265 |                                     data-content={"<button type="button" className="btn btn-danger pull-xs-left" data-dismiss="modal">Delete</button>"}>
       |                                                                  ^
```

How do I get around this? I'd like to not use jquery preferably.

Comment: Why don't you use [react-bootstrap](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components.html#popovers)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is nested ' " ',you need to use this way

```
<button type="button" className="btn btn-secondary" data-container="body"
    data-toggle="popover" data-placement="bottom"
    data-content='<button type="button" className="btn btn-danger pull-xs-left" data-dismiss="modal">Delete</button>'
    data-html="true"
    Popover on bottom
```

Comment: Or escape them with \